# Delete Sections and Keys from INI file Using Python Module iniparse?

Tags: python, ini, configparser

I'm using the Python module [iniparse](http://code.google.com/p/iniparse/) to save keys to an INI file, but I was wondering if there is a way to delete keys and sections from the INI file using `iniparse`.  I know it's possible using [ConfigParser](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html) and that `iniparse` is backwards compatible with `ConfigParser`, but I can't figure out how to perform the deletions using the same `iniparse` object.

```py
from iniparse import INIConfig, RawConfigParser

cfg = INIConfig(open('options.ini'))
print cfg.section.option
cfg.section.option = 'new option'

# Maybe I need to use RawConfigParser somehow?
cfg.remove_option('section','option')
cfg.remove_section('section')

f = open('options.ini', 'w')
print >>f, cfg
f.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove a section or an option you simply need to delete it. Your revised code would be:

```
from iniparse import INIConfig

cfg = INIConfig(open('options.ini'))
print cfg.section.option
cfg.section.option = 'new option'

del cfg.section.option
del cfg.section

f = open('options.ini', 'w')
print >>f, cfg
f.close()
```

Note that if you want to delete a whole section you don't need to delete its options before: just delete the section.

Note also that this way of doing it feels more *Pythonic* than using `remove_option` and `remove_section` methods.

Comment: @ Petro Romano.  That worked.  Thank you.  I should have realized I just had to delete the attribute.